# Add row automatically when focused on last input in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck on part of my project where user should just keep filling the form and new lines should be added automatically when user focused on last input in the form. I'm not forged in JS/jQ so maybe one of you could help me... It is working but still just from the 1st line, not from the duplicated ones. Thanks is advance

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="loadin.php">
    <!-- form header -->
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="vendor" id="vendor">
            <?php 
                foreach($vendors_ as $v){
                    echo"<option value='".$v['ID']."'>".ucfirst($v['name'])."</option>";
                } 
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice" id="invoice" placeholder="Faktrura">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Datum" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="LoadItems" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nahrát</button>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <!-- form lines -->
    <div class="duplicate" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control cleanVal" name="row[]"       id="row">
            <select class="form-control" name="category[]" id="category">
                <?php 
                    foreach($types_ as $t){
                        echo"<option value='".$t['ID']."'>".ucfirst($t['name'])."</option>";
                    } 
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="item[]"    id="item"    placeholder="Položka">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="package[]" id="package" placeholder="Balení">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="amount[]"  id="amount"  placeholder="Množství">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="price[]"   id="price"   placeholder="Cena">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="atest[]"   id="atest"   placeholder="Atest">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="batch[]"   id="batch"   placeholder="Sarže">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="expire[]"  id="expire"  placeholder="Expirace"   style="width:80px">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal x" name="vat[]"   id="vat"     placeholder="DPH"        style="width:45px">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$(".duplicate:last input").focus(function() {
    count++;
    var $clone = $('.duplicate:last').clone();
    $clone.find("input,select").each(function(){
        $(this).attr({
            id: $(this).attr("id") + count,
        });
    });
    $("form").append($clone);   
    $(".duplicate:last .cleanVal").val('');
```

Comment: Show us the response from server, for instance what is the error generated

Comment: You're going to get IDs like 'DPH1234567891011121314'

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yes I know ... this is going to be fixed in next step

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy There were no errors at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *[**`Event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) allows us to attach a single event listener, to a **parent element**, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.*

As last element is being changed every time new elements are appended, listen the event on the parent `body` or any other `fixed` parent.

```js
var count = 0;
$('body').on('focus', ".duplicate:last input", function() {
  count++;
  var $clone = $('.duplicate:last').clone();
  $clone.find("input,select").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
      id: $(this).attr("id") + count,
    });
  });
  $("form").append($clone);
  $(".duplicate:last .cleanVal").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="loadin.php">
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="vendor" id="vendor">
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice" id="invoice" placeholder="Faktrura">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Datum" value="">
    <button type="submit" name="LoadItems" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nahrát</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="duplicate" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control cleanVal" name="row[]" id="row">
      <select class="form-control" name="category[]" id="category">
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="item[]" id="item" placeholder="Položka">
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="package[]" id="package" placeholder="Balení">
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="amount[]" id="amount" placeholder="Množství">
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="price[]" id="price" placeholder="Cena">
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="atest[]" id="atest" placeholder="Atest">
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="batch[]" id="batch" placeholder="Sarže">
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal" name="expire[]" id="expire" placeholder="Expirace" style="width:80px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control cleanVal x" name="vat[]" id="vat" placeholder="DPH" style="width:45px">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y4tz085s/)

Comment: Thanks you ... $('body').on('focus', ".duplicate:last input", function() { was the key

Comment: @DaPo — I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 1):

You must define your focus event as bellow:

```
$('body').on('focus', ".duplicate:last input", function() {
   // codes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the key but since I can mark only one answer as the correct one, Rayon was first. But You were right as well. Thanks

Comment: @DaPo Yes, Royan answer is more detailed and better to be marked as the correct. Thanks